# How to clear cache automatically on symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a new route like this:

```
@Route("/restaurant/", name="restaurant")
@Route("/work/", name="work")
@return Response
```

But when I visit `/work/symfony` in my browser, it returns this message:

```
Unable to parse file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apps/symfony/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/annotations.xml": The XML file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apps/symfony/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/annotations.xml" is not valid.
```

When I clear the cache with the following command, it works:

```
php bin/console cache:clear -v
```

How can I fix this, without need to clear my cache all the time?

Comment: Welcome @heavnz0r! Next time when you post a question, try be more specific about the issue you are facing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok sorry about that ...

Comment: You can resolve it? i have the same error and i dont know how to resolver.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution by starting a symfony server instead of using XAMPP by running : symfony server:start as simple as that ...